# Can you create new sprite out of two or more already existing by taking their overlapping part

Tags: actionscript-3, sprite, overlapping

I have two spites created by drawPath(). Sometimes they might overlap each other and when it happens i want to create new sprite, which contains only overlapping part. Maybe it is really simple but i couldn't find any solution exept draw a rectangle of zone where they overlaps. So if it could be done i really appreciate your help.

```
for (var j:int = 0; j < zonesAmount; j++) {
    var sp:Sprite = new Sprite();
    var zoneCoord:Vector.<Number> = new Vector.<Number>(0, false);
    var zoneCommands:Vector.<int> = new Vector.<int>(0, false);
    var o:XML;
    for each (o in xml.ZONE[j].POINT)
    {
        var tmpCoord:int = o.@X;
    zoneCoord.push(tmpCoord);
    tmpCoord = o.@Y;
    zoneCoord.push(tmpCoord);
    }
    zoneCommands.push(GraphicsPathCommand.MOVE_TO);
    for (var i:int = 0; i < (zoneCoord.length - 2)/4; i++)
    zoneCommands.push(GraphicsPathCommand.CURVE_TO);
    sp.graphics.beginFill(xml.ZONE[j].@COLOR);
    sp.graphics.drawPath(zoneCommands, zoneCoord);
   sp.graphics.endFill();
   sp.alpha = 0.1;
   zones[xml.ZONE[j].@ID - 1] = sp;

   var picsToolt:mapTooltip = new mapTooltip(15, 15, xml.ZONE[j].SOURCE.@NMB, xml.ZONE[j].SOURCE.@SRC);
   picsToolt.Register(zones[xml.ZONE[j].@ID - 1], "");
   addChild(zones[xml.ZONE[j].@ID - 1]);
}
```

Don't bother for  addChild(zones[xml.ZONE[j].@ID - 1]) it doesn't matter

Here is examples of what i'm trying to do:
[first](http://s52.radikal.ru/i137/1403/a3/403e9484e5e8.jpg) and [second](http://s43.radikal.ru/i099/1403/0c/e5dfd2ae58a6.jpg)

Second one describes exactly in what i'm intrested, red rect is what i can do and blue line is what i want

Comment: Can you show your code please?

Comment: i'm edited it, is it enought?

Comment: I think it's enough now. I'm not 100% sure, however, because I'm not an Actionscript programmer.

Comment: oh, i thought you'll give me some tips) But still thanks for your attention

Comment: Simplicity of the solution is proportional to simplicity of your zones. Could you provide screen with some zones?

Comment: I add them as you said, do you have some ideas anout it?